# How to cancel all next requests Angular?

Tags: angular

I use the Angular interceptor:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError((x) => this.handleAuthError(x)));}
```

```
private handleAuthError(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {return of('');throwError(err);}}}
```

How to cancel all next requests Angular if at least one request return 401?

I have tried to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the latest response:

```
if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) && !localStorage.getItem("error) ){
    
         localStorage.setItem("error","true")
    
        }else if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) && localStorage.getItem("error) ){
    
    return of('');throwError(err);
    
    }else{
localStorage.removeItem('error')

}
```